# C++/Cli как определить String?

Tags: строки, c++-cli

Делаю проект CLR с WinForms на Visual Studio 2015. Не работает следующий код:

```
String str = "ABCD"
```

Пишет ошибку: "Не существует подходящего определяемого пользователем преобразования из "const char[5]" в "System::String". Как поправить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вам нужна C++-строка, пишите

```
std::string str("ABCD");
```

Если вам нужна .NET-строка, пишите

```
String^ str = "ABCD";
```

или лучше

```
String^ str = L"ABCD";
```